# Distributed Cache that supports incr

Tags: redis, ehcache, terracotta

I'm looking for a distributed key/value store that supports a balanced load of reads and writes.

Necessary Features:

1. Get, Set, Incr
2. Disk backed
3. Blazingly fast (i.e. eventual consistency is OK)
4. High availability (i.e. rebalancing load upon node failures)

Nice to have Features:

1. Overflow to disk (Assuming the load has nice locality properties)
2. Platform-agnostic (e.g. java based)

Because a lot of the distributed caching solutions support get/set but not incr, it looks like the only option that fits the requirements is terracotta.  (Though Redis has a cluster model in their unstable branch).

Any Suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

I can speak namely for redis.

> Necessary Features:

1. Yes, support also for other [advanced data structures](http://redis.io/topics/data-types-intro) like hashed, (ordered) sets and lists
2. Yes, by default redis [saves](http://redis.io/topics/persistence) snapshot of the data set on disk.
3. Yes.
4. Rebalancing load upon node failures is rather a partition tolerance than high availability in terms of CAP theorem. Redis support [replication](http://redis.io/topics/replication) and cluster is in development.

> Nice to have Features:

1. Read the article about [virtual memory](http://redis.io/topics/virtual-memory).
2. Most of the [POSIX systems](http://readthedocs.org/docs/redis-docs/en/latest/SupportedPlatforms.html).

Maybe your can try to take a look also on [membase](http://www.couchbase.com/products-and-services/membase-server) or [couchbase server](http://www.couchbase.org/get/couchbase/2.0.0).

Answer (score 0):

http://www.basho.com/  Riak will do this for you.

Comment: I don't think riak supports incr.